# Does Azure Push Notification support a user Id or alias?

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am evaluating which Push Notification service to use out of Azure Mobile Services, Parse and Urban Airship.

One of the criteria is whether the service provides a way for the app to register a bespoke user Id or alias that can then easily be used when calling the service to send a push notification to an individual. This removes the need for our backend service to have a lookup table giving us the service registration ID for a given user.

Urban Airship has the alias feature: http://docs.urbanairship.com/connect/connect_audience.html#aliases

Parse has a sophisticated Installation object which behaves like a dictionary so that additional values can be added to it (like UserId). When the Parse service is called to send a Push Notification a query can be used to specify the user that will receive the message:
https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/REST

Is there an equivalent feature in Azure Mobile Services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Mobile Services, you would need to keep track of a user to token / channel URI / registration ID association in a table which is more work than you NEED to do.  However, another feature of Windows Azure is Notification Hubs which does what you want (and much more).  With Notification Hubs, from the client you say "I want to register for Notification Hubs, here are some tags you can use to push me information".  Those tags can be anything you want including a User ID.  Later on you can tell your Notification Hub to push to anyone registered with a certain tag.  That would allow you to then push notifications out to any devices a specific user has registered.

The flow would look something like this:

1. Register with Push Provider (APNS, GCM, MPNS, WNS)
2. Send token to Notification Hubs along with tags (such as the User's ID)
3. Trigger a push to a specific Tag (i.e. User ID)
4. Notification Hubs will handle delivering a push to all devices with a Tag (again, their user ID)

Notification Hubs has client SDKs for WinPhone, WinStore, iOS, and Android so it's very easy to use from the client side.  As far as triggering pushes goes, Notification Hubs exposes a REST API you can communicate with, there is a .NET SDK, a Node SDK, as well as an unofficial Java SDK.  You can even use the Node SDK from Mobile Services which makes it super easy to combine authentication (i.e. getting User IDs) with data storage and push notifications.  It also has lots of other features like templated push notifications so instead of specifying a different payload depending on what the device OS you're pushing to is, you can have the client application indicate how it should receive a certain type of push.

Comment: Great answer, I hadn't though of using a tag per user as most examples for Tags are for subscribing to a topic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If we are using this to manage 1 million users, it is possible to use 1 million tag with azure hub basic plan ?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the pricing page (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/) it shows a "# of tags (broadcast groups)" limitation of 3k.  However, tags with 5 or fewer devices don't go up against that limit.  So you'd be able to have individual tags for each user and not touch the broadcast tag limit.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to construct the payload to include userid?